# get request works in browser, not in PhoneGap Build

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

I've looked at other examples on so and it looks like I'm doing everything right but obviously I am missing something. When run on my desktop it runs great. Once bundled into an app via PhoneGap Build, it no longer works :( wondering if anyone can spot why. All its really doing is picking out unique items from an xml response and listing them. Thanks
Mike

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TestApp</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" charset = "utf-8" src = "cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Jquery stuff -->
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function onBodyLoad(){
            //pre-loads data
            loadXMLDoc('http://login.etherios.com/ws/DiaChannelDataFull');
        }

        function loadXMLDoc(url) {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    var lastXBee=0;
                    var adChannel=0;
                    txt="<table border='0' width='%100'><tr><th>title</th></tr>";
                    x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("DiaChannelDataFull");
                    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
                        xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("ddInstanceName"); {
                            if (lastXBee!=xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue) { // if not a reading from same , start new row
                                try {
                                    txt=txt + "<tr>";
                                    txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
                                }
                                catch (er) {
                                    txt=txt + "<tr>";
                                    txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
                                }
                                var lastXBee=xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                                var sameRow="No";
                            }
                            else {}
                        }
                    }
                    txt=txt + "</table><br />";
                    document.getElementById('currentStatus').innerHTML=txt;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload = "onBodyLoad()">
                <h4>Current Status:</h4>
                <!-- **** Call to getRequestList.js file *** -->
                <button onclick="loadXMLDoc('http://login.etherios.com/ws/DiaChannelDataFull')">Refresh Sensor Data</button>
                <div id="currentStatus"></div>
                <br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess I should add that I realize that there is no id or password info in the code above, I was hoping it would just prompt me for login on the phone gap side like it does if you use a browser. If that's the issue, how would I get it to prompt me?

Comment: did you configure access origin in config.xml to allow access to your server?

Comment: Hi. I opened it up to everything and no luck access origin="*"/ . I also changed the xml phone gap version reference to 3.1.0. I also installed the app on an older android device. Additionally I tried accessing the xml data from a test.xml file I put in the same rood directory. None of these changes caused the mobile versions to work (they continue to work fine on a safari browser).

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on this and decided to go in another direction.